# Latest Ubuntu (20.10, Groovy) messes up my USB headset

Tags: microphone, headphones, headset

I upgraded to 20.10 a few days ago, and when I tried my headset today, it's all messed up. I handle audio/mic from the Sounds menu.
When I switch to a channel that lets me hear through the headphones, people hear my PC's sounds (like if I'm watching a video, they hear it as if it were my mic, instead of me talking), and when I switch to an input that takes my mic, I can't hear anything.

Info:
The headset is a Marvo Scorpion HG9055
The options I have for sound output are (I wish I could take a screenshot, but apparently you can't if you are holding a drop-down menu):
-->  HDMI/DisplayPort 4 - Ellesmere HDMI Audio [Radeon RX 470/480/570/580/590]
-->  Digital Output (S/PDIF) - Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) HD Audio Controller
-->  Line Out - Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) HD Audio Controller
-->  Multichannel Output - USB PnP Audio Device
-->  Analog Output - USB PnP Audio Device
The last 2 are the ones for the headset, Line out (3rd) is the speakers
The inputs I have are:
--> Multichannel Input - USB PnP Audio Device
--> Microphone - USB PnP Audio Device

Microphone makes my mic work as intended, but I have to use the speakers to hear.
Switching to Multichannel output or Analog Output makes the sound come out the headphones (finally) but I can't use the mic in either setting, and sounds from the system are fed as 'input', so people hear my music and themselves speak.

I can't explain how frustrating this is, since I had the same problem with 20.04 and it got randomly fixed after an update and I had it all set up (used analog output and Microphone) It works properly on my Windows partition so I know the headset is not the problem at all.

Thanks in advance to anyone even taking the time to read through all of this :)